# AWS Local CodeBuild on Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

Is there a way to run AWS CodeBuild on on-prem Windows machines?
Based on the following issue, it's not:
https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/issues/328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. CodeBuild local is only supported on Linux_x86 today. We also don't have the Windows Dockerfile available on this GitHub repo yet.(2020)